# Android file is and isn't null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

That is the best way in which I can describe what's going on.

This is my line of code:

```
if (offer.getFamily().getProfileImage() == null)
```

And this is what the debugger is showing:
[image]

Both offer and family aren't null.

So instead of going inside the if like it should it tries to get the file path and of course it fails with a `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
             at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:95)
             at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:130)
             at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(File.java:524)
             at com.yournanny.utilities.ProfileImageUtilities.showProfileImage(ProfileImageUtilities.java:109)
```

Here is where I get the error:

```
public static void showProfileImage(User user, ImageView image) {
    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(user.getProfileImage().getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

What is going on here?

---

**Update**

Looking at the comments I broke the chains and re-run it, neither `offer` or `getFamily()` return null, if I call other method over them I get the expected values.

But `getProfileImage()` is definitely returning null, the problem is that somehow it isn't null enough when I compare it in the if.

But on calling `getProfileImage().getAbsolutePath()` I get this:
[image]

Comment: Where are you calling `isEmpty()` or `getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: My guess is something is definitely null.  Possibly you are looking at the wrong section of code.  Can you list the full exception stack trace for us, and show us what line in your code it is complaining about?

Comment: I assume that either `offer`, or `getFamily()` is null.

Comment: In situations like this I often break apart the chain of method calls and instead exec them one-by-one, capturing intermediate variables for examination by debugger or logger. This also pinpoints from which statement the exception is thrown. And it miiiight have an effect on optimization. Also, check your methods for side-effects.

Comment: I added the line where it fails, and I will follow your advice and divide the method to see if I find what is null. But if `offer` or `getFamily` where null this would fail way before. Plus I now `getProfileImage` is null or at least it should be null in this context.

Comment: I dont think anything is null in here. Most likely the "path" in your getProfileImage() is null due to the file loaded from incorrect or nonexisting file.

Comment: @TsolakPetrosian it seems that that was the problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently the problem was with the deserialization of the `offer` (and particularly of the `family` inside of it).

I was getting `offer` through a retrofit get call.

I added `transient` to the `profileImage` attribute and this fixed the problem:

`private transient File profileImage;`

Now this is what the debugger shows:

[image]

So I'm guessing gson (I'm using it to deserialize the retrofit responses) was creating a file without a assigning it a path and that's why it was and wasn't null.

But a proper explanation would be great.

Comment: Without sharing your code, you are the only one who is going to be able to answer your question. Try stepping through your `User` methods while watching the filesystem. Best of luck!

Comment: @QED I was thinking it was probably the standard Gson response to not receiving a certain field when deserializing

Answer (score 0):

The `File` was non-null but its `name` was null internally.